# Parse HTML file to excel python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup and trying to parse the output to excel.

```
<div id="MainContent_BuildSheetUpdatePanel">
                <div id="MainContent_BuildSheetPanel">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 mt-2">
                            <div class="card border-primary">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">SCHOOL:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Class ID: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ClassIdTextBox" type="text" value="250" id="MainContent_IdTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                            <span id="MainContent_rfvClassIdTextBox" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Profile ID: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ProfileIdTextBox" type="text" value="NA" id="MainContent_ServiceIdTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                        <span id="MainContent_rfvProfileIdTextBox" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Serial Number: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$NumberTextBox" type="text" value="763" id="MainContent_NumberTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                        <span id="MainContent_rfvNumberTextBox" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>MC Number: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$MCSerialNumberTextBox" type="text" value="290" id="MainContent_SerialNumberTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                        <span id="MainContent_rfvMCSerialNumberTextBox" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>SK: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$SkTextBox" type="text" value="384xm" id="MainContent_SkTextBox" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Profile: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ProfileTextBox" type="text" value="NA" id="MainContent_ProfileTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$AddressTextBox" type="text" value="192.168.56.54" id="MainContent_AddressTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Dn: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$DnTextBox" type="text" value="NA" id="MainContent_DnTextBox" disabled="disabled"  class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                        <span id="MainContent_rfvoDnTextBox" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Hostname: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$PrimaryHostNameTextBox" type="text" value="N/A" id="MainContent_HostNameTextBox" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Primary: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$PrimarySidTextBox" type="text" value="N/A" id="MainContent_SidTextBox" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Server: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ServerTextBox" type="text" value="sv41" id="MainContent_ServerTextBox" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Server-Address: </label>
                                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$AddressTextBox" type="text" value="10.56.1.41" id="MainContent_AddressTextBox" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                                         <span id="MainContent_ServerIpTxtRequiredFieldValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;">Required</span>                    
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

### Expected output:

Class ID    Profile ID Serial Number MC Number SK       Profile Address         Dn Hostname Primary
 250        NA          763         290       384xm      NA     192.168.56.54   NA  NA      NA

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

html= """Inputfile """ 

for item in soup.select("div.form-group"): print(item.get_text())
```

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html= """Inputfile
"""

for item in soup.select("div.form-group"):
    print(item.get_text())
`

Answer (score 1):

You want the 'value' attribute. Depending on your full html you may be able to shorten the selectors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

soup = bs(your_html, 'lxml')

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow([i.text for i in soup.select('.form-group label')])
    w.writerow([i['value'] for i in soup.select('input.aspNetDisabled')])
```

---

Specific items:

```
soup = bs(your_html, 'lxml')

items = ['"Class ID:"','"Serial Number:"','"Hostname:"']
items = ','.join(items)
nodes = [i['value'] for i in soup.select(f'label:contains({items}) + .aspNetDisabled')]
headers =  [i.text for i in soup.select(f'label:contains({items})')]

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(headers)
    w.writerow(nodes)
```

Comment: This is working if that has value ,but sometimes i dont have value in it .Is it possible to get the required fields and value like Class ID,Serial Number,Hostname only

Comment: Do those you list all have value attribute?

Comment: yes  i have ,but i dont need all the fields instead i want only few Class ID,Serial Number,Hostname like this to csv